# Show Hide div onClick dynamically added radio button in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I need to add radio button and its associated `<div>` dynamically.

```
<li *ngFor="let ins of insuredPatientDetails">
   <div class="p-10">
      <label class="paymentcard_check">{{ins.primaryPayerName}} 
         <span *ngIf="ins.patientPaymentType === 0">(Self insured)</span>
         <input type="radio" name="patientPayee" onchange="viewPatView(ins.insuranceInformationId)">
         <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 b-t p-15 patId{{ins.insuranceInformationId}}">
      <p>show hide me</p>
      <p>{{ins.insuranceInformationId}}</p>
   </div>
</li>
```

So, If the first radio button is clicked, I need to show its div. Likewise, the div should be displayed according to its selected radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML page,

```
<li *ngFor="let ins of insuredPatientDetails">
   <div class="p-10">
      <label class="paymentcard_check">{{ins.primaryPayerName}} 
         <span *ngIf="ins.patientPaymentType === 0">(Self insured)</span>
         <input type="radio" name="patientPayee" value="{{ins.insuranceInformationId}}" (change)="viewPatView($event)">
         <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 b-t p-15" *ngIf='"patId"+ins.insuranceInformationId === patId'>
      <p>show hide me</p>
      <p>{{ins.insuranceInformationId}}</p>
   </div>
</li>
```

In ts file,

```
viewPatView(event){
    this.patId = "patId"+event.target.value;
    console.log(this.patId);

  }
```

This way I could fix the issue, thanks for the helping hearts